# Use LIMIT on two tables with an Inner Join

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

The following SQL code works fine. It has the purpose of displaying all the products ordered by each user and sorting them by products in a descending manner.

The problems occur when I try to limit the display of customers and their related products, so when i use `LIMIT 2`. I tried to insert LIMIT 2 immediately after the `ORDER BY` line, but there is a problem: I only display one customer with its 2 purchases, so in total I only have 2 lines printed.

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT Client.client_name, Purchases.product 
                  FROM Client
                  INNER JOIN Purchases 
                  ON Client.client_name = Purchases.client_name
                  ORDER BY client_name;''')
```

I would like to print 2 lines for each customer. Where and how should I enter LIMIT 2? Can you show me please? (trying not to write a too complicated sql, because i understand little of Sql and i would like to try to keep the code as simple as possible)

In the case of the example below, I would like to print **James, George, Sophie** and get this output:

```
client_name | product   |
\------------+-----------+
James      | Hard Disk |
James      | Mouse     |
George     | Book      |
George     | Keyboard  |  
Sophie     | Mouse     |
Sophie     | Coffee    |
```

The two main tables I'm using are these:

**CLIENT**

```
client_name |  born  |
-----------+---------+
James      |   1988  |
George     |   1988  |
Sophie     |   1988  |
```

**PURCHASES**

```
client_name | product   |
------------+-----------+
James      | Hard Disk |
James      | Mouse     |
George     | Book      |
George     | Keyboard  |  
Sophie     | Mouse     |
Sophie     | Coffee    |
Harry      | Cd        |
Harry      | Book      |
Lily       | Mouse     |
Lily       | Desk      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function to count assign a number to each product **per client**, and then have a condition on it:

```sql
SELECT   client_name, product
FROM     (SELECT     Client.client_name, 
                     Purchases.product,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client.client_name 
                                        ORDER BY Purchases.product DESC) AS rn
          FROM       Client
          INNER JOIN Purchases  ON Client.client_name = Purchases.client_name) t
WHERE    rn <= 2
ORDER BY client_name ASC
```

Comment: They unfairly closed the question, although in my opinion they were wrong. It's not a duplicate. Anyway now I try your code and I accept your answer in case the code works. Wait a minute. Thank you

Comment: It seems to work fine, thanks.

I didn't understand one thing: why did you write two different ORDER BY (DESC and ASC)?
Wasn't just the last ORDER BY client_name ASC enough? Thank you

Comment: @Rob92 the `order by` at the end of the query orders the results by the client name. The `order by` in the `over` clause tells `row_number` how it should order the numbering (descending by product name, as per your requirements).

Comment: If I set ORDER BY as ASC in the over clause tells row_number, what will happen? Will what I asked for no longer work? Or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: @Rob92 you'll get the first two products instead of the last two products